# How to remove new line characters in spark scala

Tags: scala

The below code is working fine in python. I am having difficulty in writing equivalent code in scala

```
map(lambda x:x[1].replace("\n","|"))
```

What is the equivalent code in Scala?

I have tried to run the below command in Scala and getting the below error.

```
scala> val read_rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/test/test1.txt").map(x => x[1].replace("\n","\u001F"))
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
```

Comment: What is yous input data? Does it contain `\n`s at all?

Comment: What did you write in Scala? Can you give us some sample input to test.

Comment: val read_rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("test1.txt").map(x => x[1].replace("\n","\u001F"))

Comment: This is what I am trying. but it is getting the error

Comment: Which error? And please edit the question instead of answering in the comments.

Comment: `x[1]` is not Scala syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sc.wholeTextFiles() return scala tuple (String, String). To access members use x._1 and x._2.

```
val read_rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("e_edge.csv").map(x => x._2.replace("\n","\u001F"))
```

Comment: you can use shorted version of scala lambda: .map(_._2.replace("\n","\u001F"))